# How to choose the top and bottom margin with amsart for a specific MWE

Tags: margins, geometry, amsart

In my long code, I have used for `amsart` the package `geometry` with lot of difficulty. After many attemps, with the parameters `left=5cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt, a4paper` I have corrected the right left and right margins.

[image]
[image]

My question is: *what are the correct parameters to add to increase a bit the distance of the top and decrease that of the bottom?*

Here there is a minimal working example with the correct above parameters `left=5cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt, a4paper`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=5cm,right=1cm,headsep=10pt,
            a4paper}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]     
\end{document}
```

A screenshot that it is not exact with the margins of my document. Excuse very much for this question. I'm writing some notes for my students.

[image]

Comment: Let me be sure I understand your query correctly: You (a) have determined that the values of the options `left` and `right` satisfy your typesetting needs and (b) now wish to find out how to set the parameters `top` and `bottom`. Is this interpretation correct
?

Comment: @Mico Yes, interpretation correct. Sorry for my question.

Comment: Add options `top=100pt,bottom=150pt,` to your command `\geometry` like `\geometry{%
  left=5cm,right=1cm,
  top=100pt,bottom=150pt, % <===============================================
  headsep=10pt,
  a4paper,
  showframe
}`

Comment: @Mensch :-)) Can you put, please, answer?

Comment: Please see my added answer ... And better use package `parskip` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you've decided that your choices for `geometry`'s `left` and `right` parameter values are fine. To set the `top` and `bottom` margins, all you need to do is set the options `top` and `bottom` to suit your typesetting needs. Thus, instead of executing

```
\geometry{a4paper, showframe,
          left=5cm, right=1cm}
```

you might execute

```
\geometry{a4paper, showframe,
          left=5cm, right=1cm, top=5cm, bottom=7cm}
```

In call cases, the length values denote distance from the respective page edges. E.g., `bottom=7cm` means "the bottom edge of the text block is 7cm above the bottom edge of the sheet of paper".

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, showframe,
          left=5cm, right=1cm, top=5cm, bottom=7cm
         }
\usepackage{parskip} % NOT "\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}"
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Package geometry has two options `top` and `bottom` for what you need. So for example you can use `top=100pt,bottom=150pt,` to be near the original spaces. Please see that I added option `showframe` to get visualized typing area and margins ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  left=5cm,right=1cm,
  top=100pt,bottom=150pt, % <===============================================
  headsep=10pt,
  a4paper,
  showframe % <======================== to visualize typing area and margins
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]     
\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting pdf:

[image]

Just play with the values for your needs ...